# Update a single record field in an anonymous record in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, record

This is not valid syntax, but is there something similar that can be done to get a new updated anonymous record, similar as using `with` with normal records?

```ml
type user = User {id: int, ... more fields}
let u = User {id = 1, ...}
let u2 = User with id = 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking how you can access the entirety of the record from a constructor, you can do this with pattern-matching.

```
# type user = User of { id : int; name : string };;
type user = User of { id : int; name : string; }
# let u = User { id=1; name="foo" };;
val u : user = User {id = 1; name = "foo"}
# let u2 = 
    let User r = u in
    User { r with id=2 };;
val u2 : user = User {id = 2; name = "foo"}
```

You can also employ `as` to bind a name to part of the record while binding `r` to the entire record.

```
# let u3 = 
    let User ({id; _} as r) = u2 in
    User { r with id=id+1 };;
val u3 : user = User {id = 3; name = "foo"}
```

Since `User {id; _} as r` would bind `r` to the entire pattern, parentheses are needed to limit `r` to just the record portion of the pattern.